# Bootstrap Modal firing event show twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web portal and trying to create a modal and when the modal open I need to call a service. But the modal is not opening and some time it is firing show event twice

https://jsfiddle.net/tiwariliferocks/gcoxuf6c/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    ConsultarEmpleador.initialise();
});

var ConsultarEmpleador = (function() {
    var init = function() {
        ConsultarDeuda.initialise();
        ConsultarDemanda.initialise();
    }
    return {
        initialise: init
    }
})();


var ConsultarDeuda = (function() {
    var ConsultaDeudaGrid, gridConsultaDeuda;

    var detalleAfiliadoDeuda = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("hii");
        var popup = PRIMAUtil.popup({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }, '#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda');

    };

    var init = function() {

        $("#open").on("click", detalleAfiliadoDeuda);
        $("#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log("open");
            $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');
        });
        $("#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log("close");
        });
    }

    return {
        initialise: init,
        verEmpleadorDeuda: verEmpleadorDeuda
    }
})();

var ConsultarDemanda = (function() {

    var init = function() {};
    var verEmpleador = function() {};

    return {
        initialise: init,
        verEmpleador: verEmpleador
    }
})();
var PRIMAUtil ={};
PRIMAUtil.popup = function(container, config) {
      container = container.jquery ? container : $(container);

      var cfg = {
        backdrop:'static',
        keyboard: false
      };



      $.extend(cfg, config);
      container.modal(cfg);     

      var dialog = container.modal('show');
      return dialog;
    };
```

Comment: You have errors in the console.

Comment: no I do not have any errors

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` This is first error in your JSFiddle. You have to rearrange your loaded scripts, first jQuery, then Bootstrap JS file. Second error is that `verEmpleadorDeuda` is not defined and you try to return it.

Comment: updated the link https://jsfiddle.net/tiwariliferocks/gcoxuf6c/3/

Comment: Another error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: verEmpleadorDeuda is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have error in your code. `verEmpleadorDeuda: verEmpleadorDeuda` is not defined on line 41, inside `ConsultarDeuda` and you are calling `PRIMAUtil.popup()` with wrong arguments order, should be
`PRIMAUtil.popup(container, config)` you have `PRIMAUtil.popup(config, container)`

I just fixed those issues here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    ConsultarEmpleador.initialise();
});

var ConsultarEmpleador = (function() {
    var init = function() {
        ConsultarDeuda.initialise();
        ConsultarDemanda.initialise();
    }
    return {
        initialise: init
    }
})();


var ConsultarDeuda = (function() {
    var ConsultaDeudaGrid, gridConsultaDeuda;

    var detalleAfiliadoDeuda = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("hii");
       var popup = PRIMAUtil.popup('#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda',{ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });

    };

    var init = function() {
       
        $("#open").on("click", detalleAfiliadoDeuda);
        $("#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log("open");
            $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');
        });
        $("#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            console.log("close");
        });
    }
    return {
        initialise: init,
    }
})();

var ConsultarDemanda = (function() {

    var init = function() {};
    var verEmpleador = function() {};

    return {
        initialise: init,
        verEmpleador: verEmpleador
    }
})();
var PRIMAUtil ={};
PRIMAUtil.popup = function(container, config) {
      container = container.jquery ? container : $(container);

      var cfg = {
        backdrop:'static',
        keyboard: false
      };  
      
      $.extend(cfg, config);
      container.modal(cfg);     
     
      var dialog = container.modal('show');
      console.log(dialog);
      return dialog;
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Modal</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="detallePorAfiliadoDeuda" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This is a large modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="open" class="btn btn-sm btn-grey "> OPEN </button> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your initialization of `PRIMAUtil.popup()`.

It should look something like this:

```
var popup = PRIMAUtil.popup('#detallePorAfiliadoDeuda', {
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gcoxuf6c/4/)